# Extract gzip via passive library

Tags: c++, gzip, nonblocking

I need to extract a large gzip data stream in C++ (on Linux) into memory. I intended to use `libarchive`, but I have the limit that I **cannot** block or use any kind of synchronization.

AFAIR in order to use `libarchive`'s *custom reader* it has to block, till data is available.

So I would like it to have the other way around. A library, which has callbacks for entries/progress and the ability to put data in manually.

Is there any library out there that does this or is it faster to modify `libarchive` to work the other way around?

Comment: Any reason you do not want to use threads?

Comment: [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/)?

Comment: @hyde Threads need synchronization.

Comment: @hyde There are lots of reasons not to use threads. Nginx exists because of them.

Comment: I assumed you can't use syncronization which blocks. If you can't use any kind of IPC mechanism (like socket pair, atomic integers, etc etc), then never mind.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Uncompression is CPU-intensive operation, so if you target systems which may have several cores, having uncompression happen in parallel, is a very good reason to use threads.

Comment: @hyde Ok, but if you have the same number of threads (or processes) as processors (to avoid oversubscription, for example), you may want to use non-blocking APIs to increase throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just gzip decompression you need and not tar extraction, then you can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/).  It is likely already on your system as zlib.h (which is also the [documentation](http://zlib.net/manual.html)) and libz.so.

If you also need tar extraction, then you can try [libtar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/).

Comment: The thing is, I do need tar extraction. Is there an easy stream based library for this?

Comment: I think this is a valid answer, since zlib does at least half of what I try to do. I asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622669/extract-tar-in-memory-and-nonblocking) to perhaps also get the tar part done.