# Extract tar in memory and nonblocking

Tags: c++, tar, nonblocking

I need to extract a `tar.gz` datastream in memory. An additional limit is that I cannot block.

Deflating in memory works great via `zlib`.

Now I need the *untar* part. Sadly all libraries I found either block or just work with tar files. Is there any library that works similarly to `zlib`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @vonbrand Because I need to extract a `tar.gz` on a server, without hitting the filesystem.

Comment: Maybe this can help:

[Stack overflow answer to question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553653/how-to-untar-file-in-memory-c-programming

Look at the accepted answer.

Comment: @LCIDFire, that tells me (yet again) what you are _trying_ to do, not what the _problem_ to be fixed is. You can uncompress via a pipe, but to unpack the resulting tar stream gives its component files, what do you want to do with them, their permissions, the directories referenced? Unpacking a tar file isn't trivial either, so I suggest looking for an alternative approach.

Comment: @vonbrand The problem is that I need to 1. download a file, 2. extract a portion of it (which is a tar.gz) and then 3. to send the file content to a library. All without having access to the filesystem or being able to block. Please provide your constructive approach for this.

Comment: @LCIDFire, let me get this straight: Yoou want to (1) get <file>, (2) extract <some.tar.gz> from <file>, (3) unpack <some.tar.gz> and place its contents in <library>? What kind of contents? How many files? What is <library> in step (3)? A directory, ...? Originally empty, filled with what? **Why** must all this be in-memory? **Could** you use other formats, other ways to transfer the data? In escence, what is your _problem_, as opposed to your solution attempt? What you propose is awfully contorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there was no suitable library before. But now there will be, soon.
Check it out [here](https://github.com/abergmeier/tarlib) but be aware, that it is not yet working.